# Contador acumulativo em javascript

Tags: javascript

É possível um contador infinito e acumulativo onde ue poça determinar o tempo que ele vai aumentar, por exemplo:

A cada 1 minuto o numero sobe, 3.001, 3.002, 3.003, e por ai vai. E tb ele não pode ser reiniciado a cada refresh.

Atualmente estou usando o seguinte código, ele me atende mas não 100% da forma que eu quero.

```js
 $('.count').each(function() {
     $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
         Counter: $(this).text()
     }, {
         duration: 200000,
         easing: 'swing',
         step: function(now) {
             $(this).text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(now)));
         }
     });
 });

 function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
     while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
         val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
     }
     return val;
 }
```

Comment: Porque não guardas o momento de inicio da contagem no localstorage ou cookie e depois vais lendo "o tempo que passou" desde esse momento? Precisas de ter esse valor numa string com formato x.xxx?

Comment: Sim preciso ter nesse formato, para seguir um padrão de outros numeros que tenho na mesma tela mas que não são contadores... Vou dar uma estudada nessa opção que vc sugeriu.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você pode implementar essa função que sempre retornará o valor atual do contador.

A ideia básica é armazenar o valor da Data atual no `localStorage` e então sempre que a função é chamada ela calcula o tempo desde então.

A subtração de data retorna milegundo. Então basta dividir por 1000 e por 60 para obter o contador para cada minuto.

Sempre que você chamar `getCounter()` retornará a contagem atual. Então você usa como quiser.

Achei legar poder passar um argumento para você ter mais de um contador se quiser, algo tipo `getCounter("contador1")` e `getCounter("contador2")`

```
function getCounter(key){
    key = key ? key : "counterDefault";

    var valueLast = localStorage.getItem(key);
    var valueCurrent = new Date();

    if (valueLast == null) {
        valueLast = valueCurrent;
        localStorage.setItem(key, valueCurrent);
    }
    else {
        valueLast = new Date(valueLast);
    }

    var diff = valueCurrent - valueLast;

    diff = diff;    //Incrementa a cada milisegundo 
    diff /= 1000;   //Incrementa a cada segudo
    diff /= 60;     //Incrementa a cada minuto
    //diff /= 60;   //Incrementa a cada hora
    //diff /= 24;   //Incrementa a cada dia

    return parseInt(diff);
}
```